# Exact drag increment.

Tags: modeling

So I am trying to drag to get exact numbers and measurements, is there a way to set the increment at which the drag tool controls the size of an object. currently when I drag I get something like 1.0574-1.0342 per drag when I want to get 1.0574-1.0573. is there a area where I can type in a number to control how slow the drag is when resizing edge lengths.

Answer (score 1):

What type of transform are you using, moving, roatating scaling?
How are you "dragging", from the transform manipulators?

If so either use hotkeys instead, <kbd>G</kbd> for moving, <kbd>R</kbd>for rotating, and <kbd>S</kbd> for scaling. That will allow you to input an axis constraint with <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> and then iput a distance, factor, or angle afterwards.

Just type the value and look in the bottom left of the *3D View* header. <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> will toggle positive or negative values. You can even input simple math expressions by entering formula mode by first typing an asterisk (<kbd>*</kbd>), then typing down any math operations desired.

If you still want to use the transform manipulators then the only way to introduce precise values is either from the operator properties on the bottom left of the *Toolshelf* (<kbd>T</kbd> key) or from the operator popup by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> after transforming.

[image]

Comment: I'm scaling, so if I wanted to do a divided by 2 math operation I would do * /2. Also lets say I wants an edge length to be 4 instead of 2 is there a way to select an edge thats length is currently 2 and just type in the number 4 and that edges length becomes 4 instead of 2 without inputting +2 or * *2 in the vector output.

Comment: Yes, first part is correct. No, scaling only works with factors, so either scale your 2 edge by a factor of 2, or type an expression to calculating more complex factors. There is no way to directly specify absolute edge length as far as I know.

Comment: One more question, are edges lengths accurate 100% or are they kinda like blenders best guess at what the length is. So lets say blender thinks the length is 2 but it's actually 1.9

Comment: No software is 100% accurate, there are precision limits inherent to computing architecture and data storage in general, but not on that order of magnitude I think. If Blender says it is 2.0 it may well be 2.0000001 or 1.9999999, but I wouldn't expect such imprecision of on tenth of indicated value.